# Legal actions on a PDA and terminology

Tags: terminology, definition, automata

I am unsure about the following so I would like to verify if my statements
are true:

1. We can remove at most a single character ($Z\in\Gamma$) from the
   PDA (top ?) of the stack with one step of the PDA [I do not know
   what is the correct terminology]
2. We can add a string of characters $(\alpha\in\Gamma^{*})$ to the
   (top ?) of the stack with one step with one step of the PDA

I would also appreciate the help with the terminology I lack (that
is, should I write top or bottom and how does a single step by the
PDA called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your numbered statements are correct for the usual definition of a PDA.

Symbols are always put onto and removed from the *top* of the stack.

"Step" is the correct word.